# summary e-mail of added items to list every day

Tags: list, workflow

I need to receive a daily summary report/e-mail of added items to list. We add about 20 items a day = 20 mail per day is really bad solution.
Can you help me to write a appropriate workflow for this?

Thank you,
Milan

Comment: No need for workflow. Just set up an alert that gives you a daily summary on all the items that were created today, really simple!

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918

Comment: It is much easier than i expected. Thank you, that is exactly what Im looking for